# MYSQL query include all "table 2" in "table 1"

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

i have this php to export date into a csv file:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("No se pudo conectar." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se pudo conectar.");

$csv_output = "Creado el, Id de Ticket, Departamento, Tema de Ayuda, Prioridad, Nombre de Staff, Apellido de Staff, Nombre del cliente, Email del cliente, Asunto, Telefono, Extension, Estado de ticket, Direccion, Marca, Tienda, Lugar de Tienda, Codigo del PC, Fecha de compra, Factura, Documento, ID, Celular, Serie del Producto, Estado del Producto, Descripcion(PyP Defectuosa), Serie(PyP Defectuosa), Proveedor(PyP Defectuosa), Factura(PyP Defectuosa), Guia(PyP Defectuosa), Fecha(PyP Defectuosa), Garantía(PyP Defectuosa), Cantidad(PyP Defectuosa), Estado(PyP Defectuosa), Comentario(PyP Defectuosa), Usuario(PyP Defectuosa), Courier(PyP Defectuosa), N°Remito(PyP Defectuosa), Fecha de envio(PyP Defectuosa)";

$csv_output .= "\n";

$query = "(SELECT t1.created, t1.ticket_id, t3.dept_name, t1.helptopic, t1.priority_id, t2.firstname, t2.lastname, t1.name, t1.email, t1.subject, t1.phone, t1.phone_ext, t1.status, t1.address, t1.pcbrand, t1.storeLocation, t1.place, t1.pcCode, t1.purchaseDate, t1.invoice, t1.tipoid, t1.numId, t1.cell_phone, t1.nserieprod, t1.estprod, t4.ticket_id, t4.`desc` , t4.serial, t4.supplier, t4.invoice, t4.guide, t4.date, t4.warranty, t4.volume, t4.state, t4.comment, t4.user, t4.nomcourier, t4.nremito, t4.fenvio
FROM ticket AS t1, staff AS t2, department AS t3, prod_cambio AS t4
WHERE t2.dept_id = t3.dept_id
AND t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id
AND t1.ticket_id = t4.ticket_id

order by t1.ticket_id)";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
for ($j = 0; $j < 39; $j++) {
if ($j <= 25){
$csv_output .= $row[$j]. " ,";  
}
$csv_output .= $row[$j]. " ,";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
}
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

I´m selecting 2 diferent tables and trying to convert them in one. 
My problem is this:

```
Created:            Ticket_id (Table 1):      Dept_name:       Priority_id:            Firstname:              Ticket_id (Table 2): 
2011-11-23 10:04:33     2                    Soporte Lima             2                   Juan Carlos                  2
2011-11-23 10:28:55     3                    Soporte Lima             2                   Antonio Arturo               3
2011-11-23 10:42:07     4                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        4
2011-11-23 10:44:33     5                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        5
2011-11-23 10:44:33     5                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        5
2011-11-23 10:44:33     5                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        5
2011-11-23 11:00:58     6                    Soporte Lima             2                   Miguel                       6
```

if you notice the "table 1" is repeating every time the Ticket_id in "Table 2" match the "table 1" how can i print somethin like thi:

```
Created:            Ticket_id (Table 1):      Dept_name:       Priority_id:            Firstname:              Ticket_id (Table 2): 
2011-11-23 10:04:33     2                    Soporte Lima             2                   Juan Carlos                  2
2011-11-23 10:28:55     3                    Soporte Lima             2                   Antonio Arturo               3
2011-11-23 10:42:07     4                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        4
2011-11-23 10:44:33     5                    Soporte Lima             2                   Renzo                        5
                                                                                                                       5
                                                                                                                       5
2011-11-23 11:00:58     6                    Soporte Lima             2                   Miguel                       6
```

blank space in "table 1" part when repeating and only print the "table 2" columns

i want to include all "table 2" in "table 1" result but with no repeating the info of the "table "1 columns instead put blank space and continue printing the "table 2" columns.
is there a way to do it?

Comment: the trick lies with LEFT JOIN. e.g `FROM staff AS t2 LEFT JOIN ticket AS t1 ON (t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id), department AS t3, prod_cambio AS t4` . Then you should not add `t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id` in your where clause. You should receive NULL instead of blank spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change output:

```
$last_ticket_id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if ($last_ticket_id == $row[1]) { $print_data = false; } else { $print_data = true; }
    for ($j = 0; $j < 39; $j++) {
        // not understand this but i leav
        if ($j <= 25) { $csv_output .= $row[$j]. " ,"; }
        // check is leav empty or not
        if (!$print_data && in_array($j, array(0,1,2,3,4)) ) {
            $csv_output .= " ,";
        } else {
            $csv_output .= $row[$j]. " ,";
        }
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
    $last_ticket_id = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks! i have one more problem.
I cant print all the info of all the 2 tables. my sql query only shows the matching rows. how can i print all the 2 tables i mean "table 1" + "table 2"?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried SELECT DISTINCT?  judging by your example result it looks like just adding a distinct would eliminate duplicate rows.